# in android studio what is the gray directory with blue square icon mean?

Tags: android, android-studio, module, icons

there is that icon which I see everywhere, and the more I see it the less sense it makes to me.

Its name is "module icon" if I understand correct, but it is far from appearing solely near modules.

take a look:

[image]

so when is this icon being used and what is its purpose?